# Cannot reach another station in wireless LAN

Tags: wifi, local-area-network

I have two stations (A and B) connected to the same wireless LAN by a wireless router (R). These stations and the router are placed in a crowded location and sometimes they fail to communicate (e.g. I cannot ping station B from A)  probably because of interference and the physical barrier between them.

I am looking for a way to diagnose where bottleneck in this communication is. In other words, I want to know if the problem is in the communication between A and R or between R and B so I can approximate these devices and possibly solve the problem.

I've tried traceroute, but it does not provide this information since the two stations are in the same LAN.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What about a ping from A to R and from B to R? Then you'll see which device is disconnected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @FrederikNielsen. Yes, this is one option, but I will not always have an easy access to B. The best solution would be to use only A to find the problem.